# Threading or activating functions with persistent variables in matlab

Tags: matlab, instance, persistent

Is there a way in Matlab to use the same function with persistent variables in the same loop twice?

The idea is to use a generic function of a Kalman filter (relying on persistent variables) to estimate two systems separately without copying & renaming the Kalman-filter-function. Some languages (e.g. G/LabVIEW) allow to define if a function should be called in a different thread and; thus, copying an instance of it, which effectively separates the persistent variables. However, Matlab is mostly single-threading only. I was hoping for a command like `subplot()` that activates different instances of a function.

I attach a dummy example, which is of no purpose (I am well aware that this is probably the most stupid way of adding constant factors to a vector;) )

```
function [i1,i10] = testThredPers()
% test function calling a local function with persistent variables twice

    % number of calles | USER
    num = 13;
    % allocate memory
    i1  = NaN(num,1);
    i10 = NaN(num,1);

    % clear persistent variables
    clear pers
    % looping
    for i = 1:num
        % 1st call of function with persistent variables
        i1(i)   = pers(i,1);
        % 2nd call of function with persistent variables
        i10(i)  = pers(i,10);
    end
end

%% --------- LOCAL FUNCTIONS --------- %
function out = pers(x,lcl0)
% function with persistent variables

persistent lcl
if isempty(lcl)
    lcl = lcl0;
end

out = x*lcl;
end
```

Comment: No, this is not possible. You will have to rewrite your function to take out the persistent variable and pass it in as an argument. `[out,lcl] = pers(x,lcl0,lcl)`.

Comment: The other option is to write a class, so that you can create two instances of it. The persistent variable is a property of the class, the function is a class method.